# Force HttpWebRequest and ClientWebSocket to use TLS 1.2

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, websocket, mono

I´m trying to connect to a websocket with the `ClientWebSocket` class. I´m using Unity 2017.4.10. Unfortunately C#/Mono is always using TLS 1.0 which for some reason fails. When i examine the connection with Wireshark i get a encrypted alert packet and the connection closes.

I already tried to force TLS 1.2 by setting:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

but still the WebSocket tries to connect with TLS 1.0.

When connecting to wss://echo.websocket.org it works, as websocket.org only supports TLS 1.2. Unfortunately my provider still supports TLS 1.0 1.1 and 1.2.
No matter what i try TLS 1.0 is always used by `HttpWebRequest` and `ClientWebSocket` classes.

I know TLS 1.0 is used because Wireshark and Fiddler says so.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a unity bug and fixed in 2018.2

[Issue](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/unity-does-not-allow-to-use-tls-version-higher-than-1-dot-0)

Answer (score 1):

for Websocket try : 
WebSocketClient.SslConfiguration.EnabledSslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please explain your answer and format it accordingly.